# One array, Two classes How do I make it so the array is available in both classes?

Tags: java, arrays

a package where with two classes. In the first one it takes an a list of words as one string. This string gets passed onto the second class where it is converted into an array separated by a delimiter. What access modifier do i have to use to make sure that the array created in the second class can be used in the 1st and where do I place it?
Thanks

Comment: tried anything recently? then show us.

Comment: bro show some code. did you start writing a single line of code?

Answer (score 1):

The classes are both in the same package - so a package protected (default) visibility is enough. If this array exists only one time in the entire program - you should also use `static` (and by this you don't require an actual instance of the class in order to access it)

However, this really reeks of being a **[code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)** if you manipulate one class's array from another class, and I would consider refactoring the code if I were you.

Generally speaking - there is seldom a good reason for a class to manipulate other class's objects directly.

Answer (score 1):

The array needs to be defined in the First class. The array has to be passed as an argument to the method of the second class where it is converted. Arrays are pass by reference. Hence the first class will be able to access the modified array.